# Find and access the element in a Priority Queue in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, priority-queue

How to find an element in a priority queue of C++11 and access the respective element? As for the following example: What would be the best to check the existence of an element in the priority queue Q and access it. Is it also possible to edit it ?

Intention: Writing an application, in which I have to check whether a particular object has been inserted into priority queue or not. If it is being inserted, then I need to access that particular object and possibly update it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <queue>

struct Person {
    int val;
    std::string y;
    bool operator()(const Person& lhs, const Person& rhs) const
  {
    return lhs.val > rhs.val;
  }
    };

int main () {

    std::vector<int> data = {5,4,3,2,1};
    Person X1,X2,X3,X4,X5;
    X1.val = 20;
    X1.y = "twenty";

    X2.val = 10;
    X2.y = "ten";

    X3.val = 50;
    X3.y = "fifty";

    X4.val = 5;
    X4.y = "five";

    X5.val = 0;
    X5.y = "zero";

    std::vector<Person> V; 
    V.push_back(X1);
    V.push_back(X2);
    V.push_back(X3);
    V.push_back(X4);
    V.push_back(X5);

    std::priority_queue<Person,std::vector<Person>,Person> Q; 

    for (auto x: V) Q.push(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can only see the top of a `priority_queue`. To see other elements, you'll have to pop items from it.

Comment: @RSahu : Yeah, I know that. Since priority queues are type of container adapters. I thought of checking is it possible/has anyone done it?

Comment: I don't think you can. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable than I can prove me wrong. Good luck.

Comment: If you need access to random elements, then a priority queue is simply a wrong data structure for your problem. In fact, I can't help but notice that you haven't actually explained the problem you are trying to solve. What's the real point of the exercise? As written, this looks suspiciously like an instance of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik : I did update the post with a brief intention of why I posted this problem. Thanks for the bringing to attention about lack of clarity in the post and appreciated for introducing to XY problem. I just wanted to avoid maintaining another data structure for keeping track of the objects inserted and removed from the priority queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this usage, I'd suggest you use a combination of `std::priority_queue` and an `std::unordered_map`.

Let's restructure your data as follows:

```
struct PersonInfo {
    std::string y;
};
```

This contains the mutable information about a person.

Now you have two containers:

- an `std::priority_queue<int>` of the values which were previously the `val`s in your `Person` class objects.
- an `std::unordered_map<int, PersonInfo>` mapping these values into `PersonInfo`s.

For your stated intent

> in which I have to check whether a particular object has been inserted into priority queue or not.

Simply check if things were inserted using the map; make sure to update it when pushing and popping the priority queue, though.

> If it is being inserted, then I need to access that particular object and possibly update it.

Just use the unordered map.

Comment: I liked your answer. Just to add it, what if the value on which the comparison is done need to be updated. How would that change the implementation.

Comment: @skn2 :-) The thing is that the value on which the comparison needs to be performed *absolutely must not be updated* - it will totally mess up the mind of the poor `std::priority_queue`, which will not know how to handle it. For some other cases (e.g., if you know it will only be decreased), you're in luck as some graph-oriented data structures do this. I suggest that - if you absolutely must do this - you should open a different question, unrelated to `std::priority_queue`, describing as precisely as possible what are the updates you'll do (drop a comment here - I'll be happy to look).

Comment: Yes, the update will happen only to decrease the value only. So, I will open a new post and post the link in here. Thanks :D

Comment: I made a separate post. Please do have a look at your convenience http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35584143/what-would-best-data-structure-to-support-priority-updating-push-and-pop

Comment: @skn2 Looks like amit answered you there. It's a fine answer.