# What would best data structure to support priority, updating , push and pop

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, data-structures

Writing an application: 
Where in I need to maintain an data structure 'X-Files' which stores a number of objects and supports following functionalities:

1. Pop - Remove the object with the least value (one of the object attributes named - 'Area51' )
2. Push - Insert the object into the data structure
3. Check - Whether the given object is in the Data structure 'X-Files'
4. Update - Update the contents of the object (Involves updating the attribute 'Area51' and its guaranteed that update will be strictly to lower value than current value)

What would be most appropriate data structure to support these requirements?

Comment: I think the Stack data structure would serve the purpose.

Comment: @A2H: How do you examine all extant values in a stack?

Answer (score 4):

A [`std::set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) should do the job.

While your problem might resembles using a `std::priority_queue`, don't fall into the trap, since a vanilla `priority_queue` does not support updating existing elements (other than the head), nor checking if an element exists in it efficiently.

Comment: I was looking into the documentation of std::set. The issues for me would be, key would be different from the attribute on which priority is. Next is std::set doesnt allows repetition of keys. I might be missing as how I can use. I hope you can elaborate little more on it.

Comment: @skn2 I am not sure I am following. Simply make sure your `Compare` (2nd template argument)  for `std::set ` is checking by the priority of an element. If you want to allow multiple elements with the same priority, make sure it tie breaks according to other properties of your object.

Comment: However, `std::set` does not support modifying the key either. The update would have to happen as a remove-update-insert sequence.

Comment: @Angew which is quite easy to implement, and pretty efficient, if you also use `emplace_hint()`.

Answer (score 2):

If the priority and the key are different attributes you can use a 2-index [`multi_index_container`](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html). Quick and dirty example follows:

**<kbd>[Live Coliru Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33eda046e65782aa)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>

using namespace boost::multi_index;

struct element
{
 int key;
 int area51;
};

using x_files_base=multi_index_container<
  element,
  indexed_by<
    ordered_non_unique<member<element,int,&element::area51>>,
    hashed_unique<member<element,int,&element::key>>
  >
>;

class x_files:x_files_base
{
public:
  using x_files_base::iterator;
  using x_files_base::const_iterator;

  using x_files_base::x_files_base;
  using x_files_base::begin;
  using x_files_base::end;

  void pop(){erase(begin());}
  bool push(const element& x){return insert(x).second;}
  bool check(int key){return project<0>(get<1>().find(key))!=end();}

  void update(int key,int area51)
  {
    auto it=project<0>(get<1>().find(key));
    if(it!=end())modify(it,[=](element& x){x.area51=area51;});
  }
};

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void dump(const x_files& xf)
{
  std::string delim="";
  for(const element& x:xf){
    std::cout<<delim<<"["<<x.key<<","<<x.area51<<"]";
    delim=",";
  }
  std::cout<<"\n";
}

int main()
{
  x_files xf={{100,0},{80,1},{90,2},{95,3}};

  dump(xf);
  xf.pop();
  dump(xf);
  xf.push({70,4});
  dump(xf);
  std::cout<<(xf.check(70)?"true":"false")<<"\n";
  xf.update(70,0);
  dump(xf);
}
```

Output

```
[100,0],[80,1],[90,2],[95,3]
[80,1],[90,2],[95,3]
[80,1],[90,2],[95,3],[70,4]
true
[70,0],[80,1],[90,2],[95,3]
```

Comment: OP didn't mention having boost.

Comment: Didn't mention he couldn't use it, either

Comment: @JoaquínMLópezMuñoz : Awesome. Appreciated. I don't have boost installed but now this compels me to install it.